# Read CSV file to Datalab from Google Cloud Storage and convert to pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, google-cloud-datalab

I am trying to read a csv file save in gs to a dataframe for analysis

I have follow the following steps without success

```
mybucket = storage.Bucket('bucket-name')
data_csv = mybucket.object('data.csv')
df = pd.read_csv(data_csv)
```

this doesn't work since data_csv is not a path as expected by pd.read_csv
I also tried

```
%%gcs read --object $data_csv --variable data
#result: %gcs: error: unrecognized arguments: Cloud Storage Object gs://path/to/file.csv
```

How can I read my file for analysis do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

%%gcs returns bytes objects. To read it use BytesIO from io (python 3)

```
mybucket = storage.Bucket('bucket-name')
data_csv = mybucket.object('data.csv')

%%gcs read --object $data_csv --variable data

df = pd.read_csv(BytesIO(data_csv), sep = ';')
```

if your csv file is comma separated, no need to specify < sep = ',' > which is the default
read more about io library and packages here: [Core tools for working with streams](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html)

Comment: In DataLab, it seems there can be only one %% command per cell

Comment: I am trying to get a filename as an input and reading from the bucket. When I do this, the data lab read only first file present in the bucket. Actually, I need to read multiple files.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to use the object's `uri` property to get the actual path:

```
uri = data_csv.uri
%%gcs read --object $uri --variable data
```

The first part of your code doesn't work because pandas expects the data to be in the local file system, but you're using a GCS bucket, which is in Cloud.

Comment: Can you provide the full code to read the < data > with pandas because I am still getting an error when I do : < df = pd.read_csv(data) > ?
" OSError: Expected file path name or file-like object, got <class 'bytes'> type "
thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is what's working for me

```
df = pd.read_csv(BytesIO(data), encoding='unicode_escape')
```