# How to read data from Google storage cloud to Google cloud datalab

Tags: python, csv, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-datalab

I have a few CSV files storing in Google storage and I want to read those into Google datalab. So far, I have no idea how to do it. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45806715/read-csv-file-to-datalab-from-google-cloud-storage-and-convert-to-pandas-datafra) and followed the first answer but didn't work and raised

```
  File "<ipython-input-1-5e9607fa3f65>", line 5
    %%gcs read --object $data_csv --variable data
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you subtract one of the `%` symbols it should work. Minimal example:

```
import google.datalab.storage as storage
import pandas as pd
from io import BytesIO

mybucket = storage.Bucket('BUCKET_NAME')
data_csv = mybucket.object('data.csv')

uri = data_csv.uri
%gcs read --object $uri --variable data

df = pd.read_csv(BytesIO(data))
df.head()
```

Comment: clean and simple. Thanks

Comment: @guillem this is for a .csv file, how can we change it so we can import a parquet file, I created a question for that! Thanks in advance

Comment: Not sure what to use instead of BytesIO ?