# How do I feed my own images into the Google Cloud Datalab Notebook?

Tags: python, machine-learning, autoencoder, google-cloud-datalab

I am trying to run my Autoencoder on Google Cloud Datalab. I just can't figure out how to use the Keras Image Data Generator. I uploaded all my images to the Google Cloud Bucket. I just don't know how to acces my data.

```
datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

training_set = datagen.flow_from_directory(
        r'DIR',
        target_size=(112,112),
        batch_size=32,
        class_mode='input')


test_set = datagen.flow_from_directory(
        r'DIR',
        target_size=(112,112),
        batch_size=32,
        class_mode='input')
```

I don't know if there is a simple way to solve this. I don't mind not using the Image Data Generator and I am open to every possible solution. Thank you very much for your time and help in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to read data from Google storage cloud to Google cloud datalab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48363259/how-to-read-data-from-google-storage-cloud-to-google-cloud-datalab)

Comment: Thank you, but this is an example for a single CSV file. I need to get my training and validation pictures and can't figure out how to do that.