# Read data from Google Storage Cloud to Google Cloud Datalab Weird Error

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-datalab

I'm trying to read a csv_file from Google Storage Cloud to Google Cloud Datalab exactly like suggested in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48363259/how-to-read-data-from-google-storage-cloud-to-google-cloud-datalab).

I keep getting the error:
Source object gs://analog-arbor-233411/traissn.csv does not exist. (analog-arbor-233411 is my bucket name, traissn.csv is my csv file.

So here I checked that the bucket really exists, and it does.

```
import google.datalab.storage as storage
mybucket = storage.Bucket('analog-arbor-233411')
mybucket.exists()
```

Here I even iterate through the mybucket.objects() which gives an iterator for the objects within the bucket to make sure that I get an existing object. So data_csv_meta only takes the last object in the iteration. Then I checked again if it exists, and surely it does!

```
for i in mybucket.objects():
    data_csv = i
data_csv.exists()
```

Here is a funny thing. When I run the following, I get the error Source object gs://analog-arbor-233411/traissn.csv does not exist (my object name in data_csv traissn.csv)

```
uri = data_csv.uri
%gcs read --object $uri --variable data
```

Tried looking everywhere, but can't get an answer.

Answer (score 1):

In your current code `data_csv.exists()` is called outside of the `for` loop, so it returns the result for only the last `data_csv` object returned by the bucket iterator, which may or may not be `traissn.csv`.

So either:

- inside the `for` loop add a `break` statement if `data_csv` points to `traissn.csv`, so that `data_csv` remains unchanged
- make the `gcs` call inside the for loop

Comment: `data_csv.exists()` is being intentionally called outside the `for` to make sure whatever the last object returned by the bucket iterator (which is stored in `data_csv` after the loop ends) exists - and it must exist because if it is returned by the bucket iterator then it exists!


Notice I never specified `traissn.csv` anywhere in the code, it is simply the last object the bucket iterator returned. Perhaps it's also worth to mention that `traissn.csv` really exists in the Google Cloud Storage.


Only after I make the `gcs` call I get the error saying it doesn't exist.

Comment: Is the `traissn.csv` object readable by the script? (often wording in error messages can be misleading)